# Angular 2 routing (routingLink behavior)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I sorry I'm still new to Angular 2, I've done my research but still confused on how routing works. Below is my route config:

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SiteLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                component: HomeComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'system',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                        component: MenuItemListComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'menuitemlist',
                        component: MenuItemListComponent,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: 'setting',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                        component: CountryListComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'countrylist',
                        component: CountryListComponent,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

My app.module looks like this:

```
// Angular2 libraries
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders  } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

// Main
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appRoutes, appComponents } from './app.routing';


@NgModule({
    // directives, components, pipes
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        appComponents
    ],
    // modules
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My app.component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'content',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>


    <!-- npm packages -->
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>


    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('./app/boot').catch(
            function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <content>Loading...</content>
</body>
</html>
```

My site-layout.component.html looks like this:

```
<a routerLink="setting/countrylist"><span class="txt">Country</span></a>
<a routerLink="system/menuitemlist"><span class="txt">Menu Item</span></a>

<br />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My application tree looks like this:

[image]

The issue is what my html looks like before clicking any links:

[image]

This is what it looks like after clicking a link:

[image]

The problems is after clicking a link, the links is not working anymore.
Sorry for the long post, I'm already desperate to solve this issue, hope someone can help me regarding this. I already seen many resource but haven't yet encountered any solution for this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
`pathMatch: 'full'`
```

to `path: ''` routes if they don't have child routes

Add `'` around the path

```
<a [routerLink]="'setting/countrylist'">
```

or remove `[]`

```
<a routerLink="setting/countrylist">
```

so `setting/countrylist` is passed as string instead of expression.

If the `<a [routerLink]="...">` are inside a routed component start the path with `/` to ensure absolute routing instead of relative routing.

Comment: hi Gunter my router link looks like this: `<a [routerLink]="[menuInfo.route + '/' + subMenuInfo.route | lowercase]"><span class="txt">{{subMenuInfo.name}}</span></a>`, it is from a class array.

Comment: Not in the code in your question (I had a typo `Ä` instead of `'`).

Comment: thank you for the response Gunter, but do you know why routing behave like what I posted on the image above?

Comment: No but I wouldn't expect sane behavior from your routerlink. You're actually passing `undefined / undefined` (`NaN`) as path. Did you try the changes I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Hi Gunter, I edited the my HTML code to show the EXACT code that I'am using.

Comment: Sorry can't imagine what causes the issue. Do you have `outlet: 'xxx'` defined in any of the routes? Have you tried adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to empty-path routes as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124959/discussion-between-arvstracthoughts-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: You should add `pathMatch: 'full'` to all empty path routes except the first one (all empty path routes that don't have child routes)

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="/">` in your `<head>` element or provide `APP_BASE_HREF` in `@NgModule()`. If not, then add it.

Comment: Hi Gunter, I had **{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }** on app.module providers, already added **pathMatch: 'full'**, will update my question to reflect these

Comment: Please try `<a routerLink="'/setting/countrylist'"><span class="txt">Country</span></a>
<a routerLink="'/system/menuitemlist'"><span class="txt">Menu Item</span></a>` (with `/` at the beginning)

Comment: Hi Gunter, it worked, can you explain it to me why? And also, can you update your answer so I can upvote it! Thank you!!!

Comment: Routerlinks are relative to the current route. If the routerlinks are not in the root component but instead in a routed component, they navigate to a route relative to the current route. Not sure why it didn't throw an error for not finding matching routes but instead do some weird navigation. I would need some deeper investigation of your setup.